# Find average of categorical values in Pandas with groupby of more than two columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a df:

```
player_id   action  level
    1   miss    level_1
    1   kill    level_1
    1   miss    level_1
    1   miss    level_1
    1   miss    level_1
    1   miss    level_2
    2   miss    level_3
    2   miss    level_3
    2   kill    level_3
    3   miss    level_3
```

How can I calculate the average kills per user in per level? I have already tried:

```
d = df.groupby(['level', 'player_id', 'action']).level.count()
```

which gives me a Pandas series of:

```
level   player_id  action
level_1    1       kill     1
                   miss     4
level_2    1       miss     1
level_3    2       kill     1
                   miss     2
           3       miss     1
```

What I just want further is the average number of kills per player per level. The final df should like like this:

```
level      average_kills
level_1    0.2
level_2    0
level_3    0.1667
```

Comment: `d.xs('kill', level=2).sum(level=0)/d.sum(level=0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
df.action.eq('kill').groupby([df.level, df.player_id]).mean().mean(level=0)

level
level_1    0.200000
level_2    0.000000
level_3    0.166667
Name: action, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

From the initial DataFrame you can `groupby` and `value_counts` then `unstack` to ensure you have `kill` and `miss` for each player who played a level. Then take the mean by level.

```
res = (df.groupby(['player_id', 'level'])
          ['action'].value_counts(normalize=True)
          .unstack(-1).fillna(0)
          ['kill'].mean(level='level'))

level
level_1    0.200000
level_2    0.000000
level_3    0.166667
Name: kill, dtype: float64
```